# Why does my laptop wifi not work after it wakes from suspend?

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend, 16.10

Just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10. Everything works great so far. Except when I "suspend" it, wake it up, the wifi does not work unless I restart my computer. The strange part is, the icon indicates I'm connected and i'm able to connect to every network successfully, but when I go to the browser its a no go. Here's the steps I've taken to attempt a permanent solution:

- turned my wifi on and off
- deleted saved wifi networks
- added networks back again and tried connecting to several different networks (still doesn't work after this)
- sudo apt update & upgrade
- Go to terminal, use sudo service network-manager restart

The final step above restarted my internet connection and within 10 seconds i'm back online again. However, I don't want to have to do this every single time I wake up my computer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Terminal :

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0
```

Solution 1:

sudo nano /path/to/script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0
```

crontab -e:

```
@reboot  /path/to/script
```

Comment: found out my wireless card isn't called "wlan0" (see below) . How do I determine which one it is?

ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
       

wlp58s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.100.59.123  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 10.100.63.255
        inet6 fe80::18f2:af03:c9cb:8235  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 30:52:cb:e7:1d:35  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

Comment: also its not on reboot it doesn't work, but instead on waking up from suspend